# Striping a string from newline markers

Tags: python-3.x, string

I store configuration data (paths to specific files) inside a file named `app.cfg` that looks like this :

```
path/to/config.json
path/to/default/folder
```

and I query those item with the following **Python** code:

```py
with open("app.cfg","r",newline='') as config:
    data = config.readlines()
    PathToConfig = data[0]
    DefaultPath = data[1]
    config.close()
```

But when I use `PathToConfig` in my script, the path stored in this variable cannot be used because there is `\n` at the end of the string.
I tried to fix this issue by using this `PathToConfig = data[0].rstrip()` but there still is `\n` at the end of the string.

**How can I strip this string from the newline marker ?**

Comment: would data[0].rstrip("\n") solve your issue?

Comment: @n4321d I tried this, but it didn't work. I got the same error, which is `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path/to/settings/config.json\n'` with `PathToConfig = data[0].rstrip("/n")`.

Comment: I think you need to use backslash ("\n"), not slash ("/n")

Comment: ah yes indeed, but I still got the same error. I made sure that I saved the file before running it

Comment: It seems to work when I tested it (I posted it below so you can see my output). Maybe try to restart your kernel/IDE? Let me know what you get when running that. If you keep getting the "\n" at the end you can use the less elegant solution: PathToConfig = data[0][:-1] and just skip the last character (which is "\n")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve it with [.rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to strip `"\n"`:

*create app.cfg:*

```
with open("app.cfg","w",newline='') as config:
    config.writelines("""path/to/config.json
path/to/default/folder""")
```

app.cfg looks like this:
[image: app.cfg]

read contents from file:

```
with open("app.cfg","r",newline='') as config:
    data = config.readlines()
    PathToConfig = data[0].rstrip("\n")
    DefaultPath = data[1]
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I created a new file with only your code + a print instruction to check the paths that were extracted and it works just fine. That's odd, it means that the problem is elsewhere because I deleted the `__pycache__` folder and rebooted, and I still get the error in the file where the code normally is. Thank you anyway. I tried the "ugly" method, but it raises the same error, so the problem must be a bit deeper.

Comment: I solved the issue, it was indeed in an other file and now it works fine !

Comment: Good to hear that you found it!